# Border and scrollbar showing when using HTML iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am using HTML iFrame to embed a chat client.

**Here is the code:**

```
<iframe src="https://kiwiirc.com/client?settings=c0671fd205dc892cbe98fd1cb315f506" style="border:none; width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute;"></iframe>
```

I have a problem that on the page a white border shows and there is a scrollbar to scroll down to the bottom of the iFrame.

How can I make it so it fits the browser window and no need to scroll down to see the bottom and also no scrollbar?

**Link:**

http://goo.gl/XgIdV9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin: 0` to your `body` tag. Most browsers have a margin defined for the body by default.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your page which is having iframe

`height:100%` and `width:100%`

which means it will cover all the screen. but your `<body>` tag too have margin of 8px which is making your iframe width+body margin bigger than the actual width as well as height.

remove the margin from body or reduce the width of iframe. it will work

Comment: @lftikhar I don't set a margin on the body. I have no CSS other than inside iFrame.

Comment: then just insert the `style='margin:0px` in your body tag, may be it is taking by default from browser default property

Answer (score 0):

insert this into the head of your page
the border was hidden, the visible border was the overflow from your browser

```
        html {
    overflow: auto;
    }

    html, body, div, iframe {
    margin: 0 px;
    padding: 0 px;
    height: 100 % ;
    border: none;
    }

    iframe {
    display: block;
    width: 100 % ;
    border: none;
    overflow - y: auto;
    overflow - x: hidden;
    }
```